# How can I track and display constant changes made in an HDF5 file with the help of python

Tags: python, file, filesystems, hdf5, hdfstore

I have this function that constantly adds a new element in a dataset array of an HDF5 file every second.

```
from time import time, sleep

i = 100

def update_array():

    hf = h5py.File('task1.h5', 'r+')
    old_rec = np.array(hf.get('array'))
    global i
    i = i+1
    new_rec = np.append(old_rec, i)

    #deleting old record andreplacing with updated record
    del hf['array']
    new_data = hf.create_dataset('array', data = new_rec)
    print(new_rec)
    
    hf.close()

while True:
    sleep(1 - time() % 1)
    update_array()
```

*The output of the print line* (basically showing the updated array..... we do not know if it is getting saved in the file or not):

```
[101.]
[101. 102.]
[101. 102. 103.]
[101. 102. 103. 104.]
[101. 102. 103. 104. 105.]
[101. 102. 103. 104. 105. 106.]
[101. 102. 103. 104. 105. 106. 107.]
[101. 102. 103. 104. 105. 106. 107. 108.]
```

I want to have a separate notebook that can track changes made by the above function and display the updated contents of this dataset present in the HDF5 file system.

I want a separate function for this task because I want to make sure that the updated content gets saved in the HDF5 files, and perform further on fly operations on them as they keep arriving.

Comment: Does this code work for you? When I run, I get several errors: 1) `h5py.File('task1.h5', 'r+')` throws an error on first loop b/c the file doesn't exist; 2) when I change the file mode to `'a'`, I get an error on `old_rec = np.array(hf.get('array'))` b/c the `'array'` dataset doesn't exist. Also the `while True` runs forever - when your run do you kill it at the command line? I can fix these errors, but wanted to confirm before I do.

Comment: Why do you want a separate log file? A HDF5 file is "self-describing" and can be interrogated. So, you can simply check the dataset to see if the data has been written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential solution attaching attributes to the `'array'` dataset. Adding attributes to a HDF5 data object are easy with `.attrs`. It has a dictionary-like syntax: `h5obj[attr_name] = attr_value`. Attribute value types can be ints, strings, floats, and arrays. You can add 2 attributes to your dataset with the following 2 lines:

```
hf['array'].attrs['Last Value'] = i
hf['array'].attrs['Time Added'] = ctime(time())
```

To demonstrate, I added these lines to your code, along with several other modifications to address the following issues:

1. Correct the errors noted in my comments (I added `create_array()` to initially create the file and dataset. I created it as a **resizable** dataset to simplify logic in `update_array()`.
2. I modified the `update_array()` code to enlarge the dataset and append the new value. This is much cleaner (and faster) than your 4 step process.
3. I used Python's `with / as:` context manager to open the file. This eliminates the need to close it, and (more importantly) ensures it is closed cleanly if the program exits abnormally.
4. I removed NumPy functions. There is no need to create an array if you are
   adding 1 scalar each time.
5. My print statement shows the preferred method create a NumPy array from a
   dataset. Use `hf['array'][:]` instead of `np.array(hf.get('array'))`.
6. I prefer to open files once (unless there is a compelling reason to open & close). That eliminates file setup/teardown overhead. I did not do this. If you want to, move the `with / as:` lines into the main and pass the resulting `hf` object to `create_array()` and `update_array()`functions. If you do that, you can easily consolidate the 2 functions. (You will need logic to test if the `'array'` dataset exists.)

**Code below:**

```
import h5py
from time import time, sleep, ctime

def create_array():

    with h5py.File('task1.h5', 'w') as hf:
        global i 

        #create dataset and add new record
        new_data = hf.create_dataset('array', shape=(1,), maxshape=(None,),
                                      data = [i])
        # add attributes
        hf['array'].attrs['Last Value'] = i
        hf['array'].attrs['Time Added'] = ctime(time())

        print(hf['array'][:])

def update_array():

    with h5py.File('task1.h5', 'r+') as hf:
        global i 
        i += 1
      
        #resize dataset and add new record
        a0 = hf['array'].shape[0]
        hf['array'].resize(a0+1,axis=0)
        hf['array'][a0] = i
        
        # add attributes
        hf['array'].attrs['Last Value'] = i
        hf['array'].attrs['Time Added'] = ctime(time())
        
        print(hf['array'][:])
    
i = 100
create_array()

while i < 110:
    sleep(1 - time() % 1)
    update_array()

print('Done')
```

Comment: Thanks, mate for your input on this. This is exactly what I wanted to mimic in my approach.